# Copy image from Google Sheets to Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, images

There's an image in a Google Sheets that I would like to insert into a Google Doc.

How can I transfer the image from the sheet to the document?

I can right-click on the image and select "Copy", but that does not seem to actually copy the image to my clipboard. If I try to then paste into the Google Docs, it just pastes the text that was previously in the clipboard.

I also don't see any obvious way of exporting the image from the Sheets, nor do I see a way to import it as an URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[You can either use keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) **or the web clipboard menu to copy and paste in Google Docs**](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161768).

The Web clipboard menu appears in the toolbar of your doc.

Comment: Please don't answer if you don't know or if you have not try. This won't work

Answer (score 8):

I have just found a simple way (It worked today May 17, 2022):

1. Shift key + Right click on the image

It opens a menu.

2. Choose "Copy image"
3. Paste it normally (Right click on the destination app and click on "Paste", or do Ctrl + V) in any application you wish, like Paint, word or others...

I hope you find this helpful, I was also pissed about this limitation from Google sheets for a while, because I was using the "export" way downloading/exporting the whole html and finding the image in the created folder... (File -> Download -> click on "Web Page .html") which I also leave here just in case it is helpful for anyone.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try dragging the image to the navigation bar of your browser, it will open the image url and you'll be able to save it to your system and load it to Google Docs.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this as of Apr 2021.

Right-click the image cell and select "Put image over cells".  Once the image becomes larger, you can shift-right click the image and now you will get the "Save image as..." option.

After saving the image to a file, scroll to the top-right of the image and you will see three dots stacked on top of one another (may be hard to see on a dark background).  Make sure the image cell is selected, and then click the top-right of the image (where the three dots are) and you will get a menu with an option that says "Put image in selected cell".  Alternatively, you can use the Undo function (ctrl-Z) to undo this.  Note that if you accidentally have the wrong cell selected, it will move the image to a different cell.  Using the "undo" function is a bit more foolproof, but either way should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to click on the image and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the image and then in your Google Doc use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. Doing Ctl+C (well, Command+C on Mac) does not copy it to clipboard for me, at least not in Chromium.

Comment: @lorin - Hmm strange, works fine for me using Windows & Chrome. How did you insert the image? Using the menu item?

Comment: I didn't insert the image, it was inserted by someone I'm collaborating with on the document.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *File* → *Download as* → *Microsoft Excel (.xlsx)*.

From this Excel file you can copy the images to other documents.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's not simple as it seems to be. Dragging the image to the URL doesn't work any more. So the only way is to open the browser developer tools (ctrl+j or ctrl+k) and locate the element to extract it's URL. Then you can insert it using the URL you found out.

Comment: Worked for me as of Oct 2021

Comment: Seems to be the best solution as of 2022