# Importing sheet into Google Docs but cell images are not shown

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, import

I am importing Google Sheet (with images embedded into cells with `=image("img_url")`) into Google Docs document but the images are not displayed, just the text data.

Any idea how to achieve that images would be displayed as well?

UPDATE:

This is the link to my Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13QgSblHXXN8ZwboBfUyDAMF1r2ohlQp-7f7DETophdg/edit?usp=sharing.

Image is included in cell A1 like this: 
`=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bblx_jApzyiJEdGyK3RIah_tVK01Iml1")`.

I am importing it in this Google Doc, page 3, under More content section: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IlXPGONrUmm7q3vXIDFcPT_qdqa-UT2bFD1M64rTaVo/edit?usp=sharing.

Text from Cell B1 is displayed but the image from Cell A1 is not.

Comment: @user0 I have updated my question with this information

Comment: I see now... unfortunately this wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to import a spreadsheet into docs, where spreadsheet contains an image embedded in a cell, is not supported by docs. the image can be only manually re-copied, but by updating the sheet it will get re-lost.

[Copy image from Google Sheets to Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12698/copy-image-from-google-sheets-to-google-docs)