# How to copy an image generated with IMAGE function

Tags: google-sheets

I am generating images through a web service into one column using the [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) function. When trying to copy the generated images through `[Ctrl]+[C]` and `[Ctrl]+[V]` it does not copy the images. Is there a way to do this or export it to an Excel sheet converting formulas to values?.

I am aware that it is possible to press `[Shift]`-Key, then Right Click every image, and click `Save As` from the context menu, but this is not feasable for 1,000s of generated images.

Comment: See [answer that suggests Save as HTML](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/164600/)